# Volcado incorrecto de datos en JTable Java

Tags: java, jtable, tablerowsorter, getselectedrow

Tengo un `JTable` en el cual muestro datos de los clientes.

Si dejo el buscador "por DNI", la/s fila/s seleccionada/s se muestran correctamente en un pintado por consola (`System.out.print`), pero si escribo un patrón del **DNI** para localizar los usuarios que cumplen ese patrón y selecciono a uno de ellos, no se me muestra el que quiero según ese patrón, sino que se muestra el primero de la tabla (sin búsqueda por **DNI**). Como si no detectase que la tabla se ha actualizado y siga manteniendo los valores por defecto (teniendo el `jTextField` de **DNI** vacío).

¿A qué se debe?

**Código Filtrar por DNI:**

```
public void filtrar_dni() {
    int columna = 0; //Es la fila del DNI.
    TRSFiltro.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(textfield_buscar.getText(), columna));
}
```

**Código (al presionar una tecla - KeyTyped):**

```
    private void textfield_buscarKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                          
        Character letra = evt.getKeyChar();
        evt.setKeyChar(Character.toUpperCase(letra));
        
        if(textfield_buscar.getText().length()>49){
            evt.consume(); //hace que esa pulsación de tecla se rechace.
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep(); //sonido de no aceptar más caracteres.
        }
        
        textfield_buscar.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
        public void keyReleased(final KeyEvent e){
            String texto = (textfield_buscar.getText());
            textfield_buscar.setText(texto);
            filtrar_dni();
        }
        });
        TRSFiltro = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>((DefaultTableModel) tabla_clientes.getModel());
        tabla_clientes.setRowSorter(TRSFiltro);
    }
```

**Código - al pulsar una fila de la tabla:**

```
private void tabla_clientesMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
        int nFilasSelec = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRowCount(); 
        if(nFilasSelec>=0)
            button_deseleccion.setEnabled(true);
        else
            button_deseleccion.setEnabled(false);
        
        int filasselec[] = tabla_clientes.getSelectedRows();
        DefaultTableModel modelotabla = (DefaultTableModel) tabla_clientes.getModel();
        
        for(int i=0; i<filasselec.length; i++){
            String DNI = (String)modelotabla.getValueAt(filasselec[i], 0);
            String nombre = (String) modelotabla.getValueAt(filasselec[i], 1);
            String apellidos = (String)modelotabla.getValueAt(filasselec[i], 2);
            String telefono = (String)modelotabla.getValueAt(filasselec[i], 3);
            String direccion = (String)modelotabla.getValueAt(filasselec[i], 4);
            String ciudad = (String)modelotabla.getValueAt(filasselec[i], 5);
            String email = (String)modelotabla.getValueAt(filasselec[i], 6);
        
            Cliente c = new Cliente(nombre, apellidos, DNI, telefono, direccion, ciudad, email);
            System.out.println(c.toString()); 
        }
}
```

**¿Por qué no me detecta el filtrado por DNI al seleccionar una fila del `JTable`?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me muestra el primer valor por defecto de la tabla, sin filtrado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]